# Writing a map editor for game development

Tags: c++

I have recently begun game development, working mainly with C++ and SDL. After creating few simple clones, I want to work on something more complex. Something with a lot more physics than I am used to, and complex game objects.

So far, I have been using a basic tile editor I made in SDL to create binary maps, but now I want to work on something meatier. Something in which I can place objects and define their properties. 2D, of course, but with more utility than a simple tile editor.

I have been searching, but I haven't really found any articles which are aimed at developing such utilities.

Where can I find information to help me develop this toolkit? And what should I use? I have been looking at Qt, but I'm not really sure. I would appreciate any help and possible guidance for this endeavor of mine.

(I know that excellent utilities do exist, but I want to develop one myself, and then hopefully integrate my basic physics engine into it. It may be re-inventing the wheel, but a very good learning opportunity.)

Comment: -1: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is too broad. We prefer questions about specific problems you have, not general "how do I write an X" kinds of things.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use existing map editors? Something specific you wish to do, perhaps? Or is it for learning how?

Comment: @ananthonline It is for learning how. My knowledge at the moment is very limited, so a project such as this is very beneficial.

Comment: @user1439707 I have updated my answer to better answer the question.  I'm in agreement with Nicol Bolas, though.  You should provide more specific questions about what you *really* need.

Comment: @Darthfett Thank you for your answer. I'll study Tiled. I'll see to it that I ask proper questions from now on, sorry if this one was too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) seems to answer most, if not all of your questions.

> Where can I find information to help me develop this toolkit?

A good place to start is by looking at open-source projects, which tiled is.

> And what should I use? I have been looking at Qt, but I'm not really sure.

You need to be more specific.  What requirements do you have?  Tiled seems to do most of what you say you need, and is written in Qt, so Qt is definitely up to the task.  It's also written in C++, which you are already familiar with.

I would recommend not reinventing the wheel, and using an existing, open-source map editor (like tiled) to do what you need.  If there's a feature you [HAVE to have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it), you can always contribute or extend the editor.

Since you're going into making a more complicated game, my recommendation is to first define your requirements.  Once you've done that, write *the game* ([not an engine](http://scientificninja.com/blog/write-games-not-engines)).

Comment: Might I also suggest Tile Studio (http://tilestudio.sourceforge.net/). It's open-sourced and written in Delphi. Definitely one of the coolest tile-based map editors I've ever seen.